# Same plugin to be used twice in a page without error

Tags: jquery

I have a page that uses "Mac style bouncing menus" once on the left side panel and then again in the footer. Basically it's just the same plugin with different images.

Either one only works, even I tried `jQuery.noConflict(true)` , doesn't help.

My question is if we were to repeat the same plugin in a page ,what need to be done to avoid the conflict? from my understanding if various plugin to be used,`jQuery.noConflict` can solve it but for the same type of `plugin`?

```
test4.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test4</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/side_style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/menuv2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />


        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
        <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/interface.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body id='superstar'>
        <div class='left'>
            <aside>
                <img src="hooha_images/logo_small.png" class="expand">
            </aside>
            <aside  class="ontop">
                <?php
                 include ('sidebar.php');

                ?>



            </aside>
            <aside>

             <aside>

                   <?php include('bottom_left.php');?>//1st Mac styled menu
             </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
        <div class='middle'>
           <font color='#fff'><center>This is the Shop With Us Page of Indonesia</center></font>

        </div>


        <div class="footer">

            <?php
          include ('footer.php');//2nd Mac styled menu
           ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class='right'>

          <?php
              include 'top-right.php';
              include 'side-ad.php';
          ?>

        </div>  


    </body>
</html>
```

bottom-left.php

```
<div class="dock" id="dock1">
  <div class="dock-container1">
      <a class="dock-item2" href="index.php"><span>Home</span><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /></a> 
      <a class="dock-item2" href="about-intro.php"><span>About Us</span><img src="images/portfolio.png" alt="contact" /></a> 
      <a class="dock-item2" href="contact-us.php"><span>Contact Us</span><img src="images/email.png" alt="portfolio" /></a> 

  </div>

</div>

<!--dock menu JS options -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#dock2').Fisheye(
                {
                    maxWidth: 60,
                    items: 'a',
                    itemsText: 'span',
                    container: '.dock-container2',
                    itemWidth: 40,
                    proximity: 80,
                    alignment : 'left',
                    valign: 'bottom',
                    halign : 'center'
                }
            )
        }
    );

</script>
```

footer.php

```
<div class="dock" id="dock2">
  <div class="dock-container2">
      <a class="dock-item2" href="index.php"><span>Home</span><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /></a> 
      <a class="dock-item2" href="about-intro.php"><span>About Us</span><img src="images/portfolio.png" alt="contact" /></a> 
      <a class="dock-item2" href="contact-us.php"><span>Contact Us</span><img src="images/email.png" alt="portfolio" /></a> 
      <a class="dock-item2" href="index.php"><span>Home</span><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /></a> 
      <a class="dock-item2" href="about-intro.php"><span>About Us</span><img src="images/portfolio.png" alt="contact" /></a> 
      <a class="dock-item2" href="contact-us.php"><span>Contact Us</span><img src="images/email.png" alt="portfolio" /></a> 

  </div>

</div>

<!--dock menu JS options -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //var $=jQuery.noConflict(true);

    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#dock2').Fisheye(
                {
                    maxWidth: 60,
                    items: 'a',
                    itemsText: 'span',
                    container: '.dock-container2',
                    itemWidth: 40,
                    proximity: 80,
                    alignment : 'left',
                    valign: 'bottom',
                    halign : 'center'
                }
            );
        }
    );

</script>
```

Comment: append your menu configuration in your question.

Comment: @Suleman ,codes added

Comment: Don't repeat the IDs. In `bottom-left.php` use `id="dock1"` (so it will be `$('#dock1').Fisheye...`) and in `footer.php` use `id="dock2"` (so it will be `$('#dock2').Fisheye...`).

Comment: @abhitalks, I tried using different ID for each and created class accordingly. But still the same.

Comment: @KalaivaniNair: In `bottom-left.php` you are still calling  `$('#dock2').Fisheye...`. It should be `$('#dock1').Fisheye...`.

Comment: PS - jQuery no conflict is actually about not conflicting with the window.$ object since some other libraries use that.  Its not got much to do with jQuery plugins etc.